# Error en procedimiento almacenado MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Estoy ejecutando un SELECT en un procedimiento almacenado en una columna VARCHAR(50) lo ejecuto desde mi codigo C# y me devuelve un error que dice "No Support the Same Name"...lo extraño es que si la misma consulta la paso como una string desde mi codigo no me devuelve error;

Sp MySql :

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`Admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `Sp_GetInfoContractNumber`( IN contractNumber VARCHAR(50))
    BEGIN
        SELECT A.IdContract, A.IdClient, A.IdClientType ,A.IdContractType ,A.ContractDate ,A.TermDate,A.ContractNumber ,A.Legal_Description ,A.DocumentFile, B.IdAnnex ,B.Name AS NameAnnex , B.BasicRate , B.IdPricingModelBase ,
                C.RFC ,C.SocialReason ,C.Mail ,D.IdClientGroup , D.NAme AS NameClientGroup ,D.IdAccountGig , D.Description AS DescriptionClientGroup,E.IdRegionalClient ,E.Description AS DescriptionRegionalClient,
                B.ActivateDate,B.StartDate,B.EndDate,B.IdStatusAnnex,
                (SELECT NAME FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS NamePlan,
                (SELECT PriceMin FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMin,
                (SELECT PriceMax FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMax,
                (SELECT PriceMonthCU FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMonthCU,
                (SELECT PriceMonthSU FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMonthSU
                FROM Contracts A, Annexs B, Client C, ClientGroup D, RegionalClient E  WHERE 
                A.ContractNumber = contractNumber
                AND A.IdClient = B.IdClient
                AND A.IdContract = B.IdContract 
                AND C.IdClient = A.IdClient
                AND E.Client = A.IdClient 
                AND C.IdClientGroup = D.IdClientGroup;           
END
```

Codigo C#:

```
public List<InfoDataAdmClient> ListadoContractNumberSp(string SpName, string contractNumber )
{
    List<InfoDataAdmClient> InfoDataAdmClient = new List<InfoDataAdmClient>();
    DataTable dataTabla = new DataTable();
    MySqlConnection Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion);
    using (Conexion)
    {
        Conexion.Open();
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(SpName, Conexion);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        new MySqlParameter("@contractNumber",contractNumber);
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdaptador.Fill(dataTabla); ***//AQUI EL ERROR***
        Conexion.Close();
    }
    EngineApi Funcion = new EngineApi();
    InfoDataAdmClient = Funcion.ConvertirToListInfoDataAdmClient(dataTabla);
    return InfoDataAdmClient;
}
```

Imagen del error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo hago de esta forma si me lo hace bien ...

```
public List<InfoDataAdmClient> InfoDataAdmClientNumber(string  contractNumber)
{
    List<InfoDataAdmClient> infoDataAdmClient = new List<InfoDataAdmClient>();
    EngineDb Metodo = new EngineDb();
    // infoDataAdmClient = Metodo.ListadoContractNumberSp("Sp_GetInfoContractNumber", contractNumber);
    string SQL= "SELECT  A.IdContract,A.IdClient ,A.IdClientType ,A.IdContractType ,A.ContractDate ,A.TermDate,A.ContractNumber ,A.Legal_Description ,A.DocumentFile, B.IdAnnex ,B.Name AS NameAnnex , B.BasicRate , B.IdPricingModelBase ," +
    " C.RFC ,C.SocialReason ,C.Mail ,D.IdClientGroup , D.NAme AS NameClientGroup ,D.IdAccountGig , D.Description AS DescriptionClientGroup,E.IdRegionalClient ,E.Description AS DescriptionRegionalClient," +
    " B.ActivateDate,B.StartDate,B.EndDate,B.IdStatusAnnex," +
    " (SELECT NAME FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS NamePlan," +
    " (SELECT PriceMin FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMin," +
    " (SELECT PriceMax FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMax," +
    " (SELECT PriceMonthCU FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMonthCU," +
    " (SELECT PriceMonthSU FROM PricingModelBase WHERE IdPricingModel = B.IdPricingModelBase) AS PriceMonthSU " +
    " FROM Contracts A, Annexs B, Client C, ClientGroup D, RegionalClient E  WHERE " +
    " A.ContractNumber =" + "'" + contractNumber + "'"  + " AND A.IdClient = B.IdClient AND A.IdContract = B.IdContract AND C.IdClient = A.IdClient AND E.Client = A.IdClient AND C.IdClientGroup = D.IdClientGroup";
    infoDataAdmClient = Metodo.ListadoContractNumber(SQL, contractNumber);
    return infoDataAdmClient;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que nunca asignas el parametro, solo haces el `new` pero lo dejas en e aire sin asignar a la coleccion `Parameters`

```
public List<InfoDataAdmClient> ListadoContractNumberSp(string contractNumber)
{
    List<InfoDataAdmClient> InfoDataAdmClient = new List<InfoDataAdmClient>();
    DataTable dataTabla = new DataTable();

    using (MySqlConnection Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion))
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Sp_GetInfoContractNumber", Conexion);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var contractParam = new MySqlParameter("?contractNumber",contractNumber);
        command.Parameters.Add(contractParam);

        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
        dataAdaptador.Fill(dataTabla);
    }

    EngineApi Funcion = new EngineApi();
    InfoDataAdmClient = Funcion.ConvertirToListInfoDataAdmClient(dataTabla);

    return InfoDataAdmClient;
}
```

Te estan faltando estas lineas

```
var contractParam = new MySqlParameter("?contractNumber",contractNumber);
command.Parameters.Add(contractParam);
```

donde asignas el parametro al `command`

**Nota**: prueba si el nombre del parametro no debe ir con `?` en lugar de `@` ya que este se suele usar para sql server

Comment: Hola ...Leandro ... Agregue la linea que me sugieres ..Igual me sigue devolviendo el mismo error

Comment: pero intentaste definir el parametro con el `?` o quizas dejarle el `@` no recuerdo si estos eran necesario seria cuestion de probar https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-stored-using.html

Answer (score 0):

pude solucionar modificando mi codigo c# desde donde invoco el Sp

```
   public List<InfoDataAdmClient> ListadoContractNumberSp(string SpName, string contractNumber )
        {
            List<InfoDataAdmClient> InfoDataAdmClient = new List<InfoDataAdmClient>();
            DataTable dataTabla = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnection Conexion = new MySqlConnection(StringConexion);
            using (Conexion)
            {
                Conexion.Open();
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(SpName, Conexion);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contractNumber",contractNumber);
                command.Parameters["@contractNumber"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                MySqlDataAdapter dataAdaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                dataAdaptador.Fill(dataTabla);
                Conexion.Close();
            }
            EngineApi Funcion = new EngineApi();
            InfoDataAdmClient = Funcion.ConvertirToListInfoDataAdmClient(dataTabla);
            return InfoDataAdmClient;
        }
```